Font Not Loading in FabricJS Canvas with WebFontLoader (Dynamic Import)
I'm working on a Nextjs project where I need to load a custom font (Rasa from Google Fonts) into a FabricJS canvas, but I'm encountering an issue where the font is not applied until after I interact with the canvas (e.g., clicking on any text).
Steps to Reproduce:

I am using the webfontloader library to load a Google Font dynamically when the component mounts.

I initialize a FabricJS canvas using fabricjs-react.

I try to render text (IText objects) onto the canvas after the font is loaded, applying a scale factor and some custom styling.


However, the font doesn't seem to apply correctly to the text objects initially. The text is rendered with the default font, and only when I click on the text (or interact with the canvas) does it update and display with the correct font.

"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { FabricJSCanvas, useFabricJSEditor } from "fabricjs-react";
import { ProductResponse } from "@/lib/store/slices/products/products.type";
import { useScaleFactor } from "@/hooks/useScaleFactor";
import { removePx } from "@/lib/utils/stringUtil";
import { IText } from "fabric";

const EditingArea = (
  { height, width, cardData }:
    { height: string; width: string; cardData: ProductResponse; }
) => {

  const { editor, onReady } = useFabricJSEditor();
  const { containerRef, scaleFactor } = useScaleFactor({ height: removePx(height) });

  const cardHeight = removePx(height);
  const cardWidth = removePx(width);

  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);  // State to track font loading
  const [textRendered, setTextRendered] = useState(false);  // State to track if text is rendered

  // Load the font with webfontloader
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      import("webfontloader").then((WebFontLoader) => {
        WebFontLoader.load({
          google: {
            families: ['Rasa'],  // You can add more fonts here if needed
          },
          active: function () {
            console.log("Font loaded");
            setFontLoaded(true);  // Update state once font is loaded
          },
          inactive: function () {
            console.error("Font failed to load");
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }, []);  // Only runs once when the component mounts

  // Render text once the font is loaded and scale factor is ready
  useEffect(() => {
    if (fontLoaded && editor && cardData && scaleFactor) {
      const canvas = editor.canvas;
      canvas.clear();  // Clear the existing canvas

      // Ensure that the canvas has been properly initialized
      if (!canvas) {
        console.error("Canvas is not initialized yet.");
        return;
      }

      // Create text objects based on the `cardData` (assuming `cardData.texts` exists)
      const fabricTextObjects = cardData.data.cards[0].content.map((__text) => {
        return new IText(__text.text, {
          left: removePx(__text.left) * scaleFactor,  // Apply scale factor for positioning
          top: removePx(__text.top) * scaleFactor,
          fill: __text.color,
          fontSize: removePx(__text.fontSize) * scaleFactor,  // Apply scale factor for font size
          fontFamily: __text.fontFamily || "Rasa",  // Apply the loaded font
          textAlign: __text.textAlign || "center",  // Default to center alignment
        });
      }) || [];

      // Add text objects to the canvas
      if (fabricTextObjects.length > 0) {
        canvas.add(...fabricTextObjects);

        // Update coordinates and render the canvas
        canvas.forEachObject((obj) => {
          if (obj instanceof IText) {
            obj.setCoords();  // Recalculate coordinates
          }
        });

        canvas.renderAll();  // Render all objects
        setTextRendered(true);  // Set the textRendered state
      }
    }
  }, [fontLoaded, editor, cardData, scaleFactor]);  // Only runs when these dependencies change

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={containerRef} className="h-full w-full">
        {scaleFactor ? (
          <div style={{ height: cardHeight * scaleFactor, width: cardWidth * scaleFactor }}>
            <FabricJSCanvas className="bg-white h-full w-full" onReady={onReady} />
          </div>
        ) : (<></>)}
      </div>

      {textRendered && (
        <div>
          <p>Text has been rendered!</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default EditingArea;

What I Expect:

The font Rasa should be applied to the IText objects when they are rendered on the FabricJS canvas.

The canvas should render the text correctly with the custom font immediately, without needing to click on it.


What Happens:

The text is initially rendered with the fallback font.

When I interact with the text (click on it or trigger some other event), the font updates and the text is displayed correctly.

The font does not apply to the text objects until after an interaction with the canvas.


Troubleshooting I've Done:

I verified that webfontloader is correctly loading the font by logging to the console ("Font loaded").

I ensured that fontLoaded is set to true before rendering any text.

The editor and canvas are properly initialized before I attempt to add text objects.

I tried clearing the canvas (canvas.clear()) before adding new text objects to avoid any leftover items from previous renders.


Questions:

Why is the font not being applied to the text objects initially?

Is there an issue with how I'm handling dynamic font loading and rendering text on the FabricJS canvas?

How can I ensure that the font is applied immediately without the need for any interaction (e.g., clicking) to trigger the font update?


Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The issue is probably just the fact that, although the CSS file might be loaded, the font files it references might still be coming in. FabricJS doesn't update unless necessary, so you would have to wait for everything to be loaded before you render
